# Playing video with opencv

Tags: c, opencv

I have this code here to play a video. When I compile it, it does so fine but when I run, it just does nothing. What could be the problem? Is it the code? Or are my video dependencies not installed properly?

```
#include <highgui.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
     /* Create a window */
     cvNamedWindow("Example2", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
     /* capture frame from video file */
     CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture( argv[1]);
     /* Create IplImage to point to each frame */
     IplImage* frame;
     /* Loop until frame ended or ESC is pressed */
     while(1)
     {
        /* grab frame image, and retrieve */
        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
        /* exit loop if fram is null / movie end */
        if(!frame) break;
        /* display frame into window */
        cvShowImage("Example2", frame);
        /* if ESC is pressed then exit loop */
        char c = cvWaitKey(33);
        if(c==27) break;
     }

     /* destroy pointer to video */
     cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
     /* delete window */
     cvDestroyWindow("Example2");

     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: When you run it, is at least a window opened?

Comment: NO, no window opens. It just returns to the command line

Comment: how are you running it? You are telling it what to open right?
start by putting a cout in the while loop to see if it ever gets in there. Also, since it seems like you're just starting, I would highly recommend you to use openCV2's C++ API. IplImage is from the old C API, which is less readable and less easy to use.

Comment: i'm using this command ./executable filename to run it

Comment: What operation system do you have? On **mac** you can compile to command line command, but then you cannot run it as a windowed application. (So you need to use an IDE -- say XCode or Qt Creator)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly giving the name of the file through command line, try passing the file name in the parameter and see if the video gets displayed or not,provide full path of the file in parameters. If it doesn't then we'll try figuring out if there is something wrong with the OS or with the video dependencies.

Currently it seems to me as if you are not providing a proper path for the file.

what is the format of the video that you are using??

Also check if the video file is getting loaded or not.

`if(!capture)`

`{`

`//Just to check if the video gets loaded or not`

`printf("Video Can't be loaded");`

    `getch();`

`System.exit(0);`

`}`

Hope that helps.